# ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed (Django Middleware)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I am creating Django middleware for blocking a user when (s)he gets throttled more than 5 times but I am getting `ContentNotRenderedError`.

#### Full error msg:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Application/utilities/anaconda3/envs/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/Application/utilities/anaconda3/envs/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/user/Application/utilities/anaconda3/envs/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 113, in process_response
    response.headers['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))
  File "/home/user/Application/utilities/anaconda3/envs/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 126, in content
    raise ContentNotRenderedError(
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.
[22/Mar/2022 11:55:03] "GET /api/v1/userdetail/ HTTP/1.1" 500 84321
```

#### Middleware class

```py
class BlockMiddleware:
    
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # some other variables
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        # handle_blocking will return "None" if user can access application else "rest_framework.response.Response" object
        blocking_res = self.handle_blocking(request)
        if blocking_res:
            return blocking_res

        response = self.get_response(request)
        # logic for counting how many throttles have left
        # then
        if throttles_left <= 0:
            return Response(
                    data='User is blocked due to exceeding throttles limit.',
                    status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
                )
        else:
            return response
```

Example return of `handle_blocking` function:

```py
return Response(
    data='User is blocked, please contact the support team.',
    status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
)
```

It works when I remove the middleware and don't use the `Response` class(return the self.get_response(request) instead).
I am unable to figure out the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to return a `Response` instance, you need to set some properties before returning it:

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class BlockMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        blocking_res = self.handle_blocking(request)
        if blocking_res:
            return blocking_res

        response = self.get_response(request)
        if throttles_left <= 0:
            response = Response(
               data='User is blocked due to exceeding throttles limit.',
               status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
            )
            response.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
            response.accepted_media_type = "application/json"
            response.renderer_context = {}
            response.render()
            return response
        else:
            return response
```

You need to do the same also in your `handle_blocking` implementation, for example:

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
response = Response(
    data='User is blocked, please contact the support team.',
    status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
)
response.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
response.accepted_media_type = "application/json"
response.renderer_context = {}
response.render()
return response
```

These properties are generally set by the `api_view` decorator that cannot be used with middlewares, so you must set them manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I already tried `django.http.JsonResponse` and it was working, but the problem is with `rest_framework.response.Response`, I have other custom middleware and it's working fine there.

Comment: @rain I have edited my answer, now it works with `Response`

Comment: Not working, prompting the same error, but yeah, it is happening because of the `api_view` decorator. Please revert your answer, accepting that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @rain Try to call `render` on the `Response` instance after having set the other properties (I have updated my answer to show this)

Comment: Yes, that worked. Can you share any doc/reference link which you used?

Comment: @rain Great. Sure I read the documentation about the [Response object](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) and then I tried to set various `Response` properties

Answer (score 0):

Go for 'reponse.data' if you are using RequestFactory. It worked in my case to fetch respose data.